# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, bsod

I get a DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION error sometimes (not every time) when I start a PC on which Windows 8.1 has been newly installed.

I've got some minidump files and I think there could be found some information about what caused the crash, but I don't know how to read them.
I've shared the minidump files here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8q9luuvcnbk28a6/minidump.zip?dl=0
Any help with the interpretation of these file will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use windbg to determine what likely is a bad device driver.  Update your question once you have identified the driver.

Comment: @Ramhound I already posted what I see from the dmp. It is a firewire driver from 2010 which causes the crash

Comment: @sasbs anx update on the issue? Does removing the driver fixes it?

Answer (score 2):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks), shows that the driver `firedrv.sys` (firewire driver) cause the crash:

```
DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)
The DPC watchdog detected a prolonged run time at an IRQL of DISPATCH_LEVEL
or above.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, A single DPC or ISR exceeded its time allotment. The offending
    component can usually be identified with a stack trace.
Arg2: 0000000000000501, The DPC time count (in ticks).
Arg3: 0000000000000500, The DPC time allotment (in ticks).
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------

*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for firedrv.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for firedrv.sys

DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  6.3.9600.18292 (winblue_ltsb.160330-1744)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Acer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  Veriton X2632G 

BIOS_VENDOR:  Acer                    

BIOS_VERSION:  P21-B4                 

BIOS_DATE:  04/03/2015

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Acer

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Veriton X2632G

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!KeClockInterruptNotify
03 hal!HalpTimerClockIpiRoutine
04 nt!KiCallInterruptServiceRoutine
05 nt!KiInterruptSubDispatchNoLockNoEtw
06 nt!KiInterruptDispatchLBControl
07 firedrv
08 0x0
09 firedrv
0a 0x0

IMAGE_NAME:  firedrv.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4c21cc64

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  af0c

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x133_DPC_firedrv!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  0x133_DPC_firedrv!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x133_DPC_firedrv!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x133_dpc_firedrv!unknown_function


fffff800`6314e000 fffff800`63170000   firedrv  T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: firedrv.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\firedrv.sys
    Image name: firedrv.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Wed Jun 23 10:57:08 2010
```

Update or remove the driver and the issue should be gone.